# Problem in horizontal stacked bar graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart, stacked-chart

Below is my code which creates horizontal stacked bar graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

year = [2014]  
tutorial_public = [30]  
tutorial_premium = [10]
tutorial_premiumx = [20] 

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1)

axs.barh(year, tutorial_premium, color="yellow")  
axs.barh(year, tutorial_public, left=tutorial_premium, color="red")
axs.barh(year, tutorial_premiumx, left=tutorial_public, color="blue")
```

It produces the below image : 
[image]

What i find absurd here is that length of the red part is only 20 but it should be 30 because `tutorial_public = [30]` . What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width of the red bar *is* 30, your problem is that you have hidden part of the bar with the blue bar (try it by commenting the last line of your code)

You need to adjust the `left=` argument of your third `barh` (Notice that I have converted your list to numpy arrays to facilitate arithmetic operations):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

year = [2014]  
tutorial_public = np.array([30])
tutorial_premium = np.array([10])
tutorial_premiumx = np.array([20])

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1)

axs.barh(year, tutorial_premium, color="yellow")  
axs.barh(year, tutorial_public, left=tutorial_premium, color="red")
axs.barh(year, tutorial_premiumx, left=tutorial_premium+tutorial_public, color="blue")
```

Comment: You saved me from lot of head scratching!